# How to print the years between year1=1990 and year2=2000?

Tags: mongodb

I wrote the code for printing the years which is less than 2013 and greater than 1800 like

```
collection.find({ $and: [ { "year": { $gte: 1800 } }, { "year": { $lt: 2013 } } ] } )
```

But it is not showing any result. How can we use the `$lte` and `$gte` to get the output?

Answer (score 1):

```
collection.find({ "year": { $gte: 1800, $lt: 2013 } } )
```